# Database not updating based on the values from API

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, api, express

I'm trying to update the status for every ticket in the database by fetching all the tickets from database and then passing it to the API.
The API returns me a status which I want to update against every ticket in the database.
My code looks fine to me, but the table is not being updated.
I tried console.log() for both **ticketNumber** as well as **info.status.name**, they both are printing correct values as well.

NOTE: URL is a combination of urlcomeshere/ticketNumber
something like https://api-example.com/BCA-123

```js
connection.query(`SELECT ticket_Number FROM tickets`, function(
  err,
  result,
  fields
) {
  var totalTickets = result.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < totalTickets; i++) {
    ticketNumber = result[i].ticket_Number;
    var infix = "urlcomeshere/";
    infix += ticketNumber;
    var options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: infix,
      auth: {
        username: "username comes here",
        password: "password comes here"
      },
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json"
      }
    };

    request(options, function(error, response, body) {
      info = JSON.parse(body)["fields"];
      var updateTickets = `UPDATE tickets SET status = "${info.status.name}" WHERE ticket_Number = "${ticketNumber}"`;
      connection.query(updateTickets, function(err, result) {
        console.log("Updated ticket Status");
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is you are calling an async function your application won't know when will it end or execute, and the thread might be ended before your query is executed.

Below the example i tried to separate the query function and promisify it.

Read:
[Promisification](https://javascript.info/promisify)

```
const somefunction = () => {
  connection.query(`SELECT ticket_Number FROM tickets`, function(
    err,
    result,
    fields
  ) {
    var totalTickets = result.length;
    const promises = []
    for (var i = 0; i < totalTickets; i++) {
      ticketNumber = result[i].ticket_Number;
      var infix = "urlcomeshere/";
      infix += ticketNumber;
      var options = {
        method: "GET",
        url: infix,
        auth: {
          username: "username comes here",
          password: "password comes here"
        },
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json"
        }
      };
      promises.push(updateTicketQuery(options, body, ticketNumber))
    }
    await Promise.all(promises)
  });
}

const updateTicketQuery = (options, body, ticketNumber) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(options, function(error, response, body) {
        coonst info = JSON.parse(body)["fields"];
        var updateTickets = `UPDATE tickets SET status = "${info.status.name}" WHERE ticket_Number = "${ticketNumber}"`;
        connection.query(updateTickets, function(err, result) {
          if(err) {
            reject(err)
          } else {
            console.log("Updated ticket Status");
            resolve(result)
          }
        });
      });
  })
}
```

Comment: This snippet is not working for me, it makes my server.js to crash.

Comment: await is only valid in async function

Comment: connection.query(`SELECT ticket_Number FROM tickets`, await function(

Comment: missing one await, but the code is not tested, so it might contain bug. read more about async await https://javascript.info/async-await